# Is it secure to use database primary key values in API directly

Tags: database, security

I have a database which has particular table "Attribs" that contains a list of attributes for a user like name, address, phone number etc. each of which is the key. The REST API I have uses this table to get attribute name and fills up another table. However, the keys in "Attribs" are being exposed in API.

e.g. if I am trying to put user name which is an attribute user_name then my REST API will have a line like

"user_name":"abcd"

Is is safe to expose these keys or may it cause any possible security issues?

Comment: That sounds pretty safe. I mean, as long as these primary key values are supposed to be confidential. But then you wouldn't even need to ask. To be sure, what's the security goal here?

Comment: The API is used by many people(directly or indirectly) to create data. This data is sent in the form of key:value where key comes from "Attrib" and is stored in other table "users". So the key from Attrib is a column name in users. If someone were to try and hack in to users, that would leak a lot of sensitive information. So I am wondering if the design of the system is giving out the information that would make a hackers job easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't have enough context but no, it is an insecure practice, and there is an entire section on OWASP about it. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References It is a principle, do not directly expose IDs, but use and indirection layer.

Impacts in your case are not assessable with the description you provide, but I would apply the principle if I was you :)

Comment: This is primary an issue of proper authorization. If your authorization is flawless, it doesn’t really matter whether the ID you’re using to refer to an object is predictable or not. On the other hand, authorization should not be based on the knowledge of the ID only.

Comment: Why do you say that? What if the auth is flawless but you have 100.000 users, and with a user you can enumerate the "ID" supposed to be seen only by that user? Another thing, a reliable ID on the DB is used in conjunction with **other problems**. Let's say someone finds a way to write on a table of the database, but he can't read; with a direct exposure of an ID like that he could read the database, basically writing in the ID the content of another row. Or if anyone needs a known value in the DB to exploit a vulnerability, he will know any of those IDs exist.

Comment: If someone is trying to hack the database, how much easier would it be with known column names of a table? There is a authentication mechanism is in place but then again API can also be used for authentication which means it exposes column names in "authentication_info" table.

Comment: it would definitely save an attacker some trouble if they knew the column names. but don't go crazy pursuing security through obscurity.